# Connecting ListView and Image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have a PictureBox which contains multiple images and a ListView. What I want to do is when I click on the PictureBox image that is clicked on changes color (this part is accomplish). And ListItem that represents that image in ListView is Selected also whenever I select an Item from ListView the image representing it selected so it changes color.

My Idea is to send a `PictureBox_Mouse_Down()` event whenever `ListView_ItemSelectionChanged()` occurs and update the `SelectedItem` whenever I click on an image.

I wanted to ask if there is a common way to connect these to items maybe via ListView Properties?

Thanks.

Comment: Use data-binding.  And bind both controls so they are separately notified when changes are made.  You really don't want to have controls know about each other when it's data driven.

Comment: @Zer0 so I better use Listbox instead of ListView?